# How to get only div with not style attribute?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Suppose I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="table-container"></div>
<div class="table-container" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="table-container" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="table-container"></div>
```

how can I get only the `div` with no `style` attribute? I did this:

```
HtmlNodeCollection containers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='table-container']");
```

there is a property that allow me to do that?

Comment: `//div[@class='table-container' and not(@style)]` ?

Comment: @splash58 didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your'e close. Just add a `Where`:

```
var nodes = doc
   .DocumentNode
   .ChildNodes
   .Where(n => n.Attributes.Count == 1 && 
               n.Attributes[0].Name == "class")
   .ToList();
```